# ipad rootviewcontroller not reloading data after passing value from detailviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

[image]I have a splitview that has some modal views being loaded to do some initial configurations. After the final step of that configuration procedure user needs to pick an option and depending on that option the rootviewcontroller needs to reload the data.

I have the following codes:

This is from the button of the last view of the configuration

```
RootListViewController *rootMenu = [[RootListViewController alloc]init];
rootMenu.matNum = matnum;
[rootMenu.tableView reloadData];


[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PushToMainStaff" sender:self];
```

This is the RootListView

```
@implementation RootListViewController
@synthesize matNum;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"viewdidload root");


    if(matNum > 0){
        // just a test
        brackets = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Category 1", @"Category 2", @"Category 3", nil];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

}
```

And this is the cell that would display the details on that rootview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CategoryCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel.text = [brackets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

When I step through it wouldn't go through the

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

method.It would just trigger the **reloadData** and then the **viewDidLoad** but that's it. So not sure if the I'm doing the passing correctly or the way I'm dealing with the whole flow is wrong?

Any thoughts? I can post the storyboard as well if needed.

Thanks!!

Comment: Is it possible that you haven't set your tableView's dataSource?

Comment: hmm.. unless im doing it wrong i see that the delegate and datasource is connected to my Root View class.

Comment: are you getting into your if (matNum>0)?

Comment: yes. the brackets gets populated as well. but it wouldn't go through the - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: that populates the cells

Comment: That being the case, I don't think there's enough information here. Are any of your UITableViewDataSource methods being called? I take it you're not seeing any exception thrown? Did you hook up your table view's delegate and data source in storyboard or in code? Seeing your storyboard might help, actually, if you select your instance of RootListViewController with the connections inspector showing.

Comment: I attached the connection of the delegate and the datasource. And yes no exception being thrown.